# How to handle checked and indeterminate in vuetify v-checkbox?

Tags: vuetify.js

I am trying to switch checked and indeterminate status in vuetify v-checkbox. Sometimes it works but most of the time it doesn't. What am I doing wrong? I want to set the indeterminate -> true of first checkbox by checking the second checkbox

```
<v-template>

  <v-checkbox
     v-model="item_1.checked"
     :indeterminate="item_1.indeterminate"
   ></v-checkbox>

   <v-checkbox
    @change="onTest($event)"
     v-model="item_2.checked"
     :indeterminate="item_2.indeterminate"
   ></v-checkbox>
</v-template>
<script>
    methods: {
        onTest(event) {
            if(event) {
                this.item_1.indeterminate = true;
                this.item_1.checked = false;
            }
        } 
    }
    data(){
        return {
            item_1: {
                    name: 'test 1'
                    checked: false,
                    indeterminate: false
                },
            item_2: 
                {
                    name: 'test 1'
                    checked: false,
                    indeterminate: false
                },

        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated code, it is working fine now

```
<v-template>
    <div id="app">
        <v-app id="inspire">
            <div>
                <v-checkbox
                    @change="onTest($event, 1, 2)"
                    v-model="item_1.checked"
                    :indeterminate="item_1.indeterminate"
                ></v-checkbox>
                <v-checkbox
                    @change="onTest($event, 2, 1)"
                    v-model="item_2.checked"
                    :indeterminate="item_2.indeterminate"
                ></v-checkbox>
            </div>
        </v-app>
    </div>
</v-template>
<script>
    new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    methods: {
        onTest(event, value, next) {
            if (event) {
                this[`item_${next}`].checked = false;
                this[`item_${next}`].indeterminate = true;
            } else {
                this[`item_${value}`].checked = false;
                this[`item_${value}`].indeterminate = true;
            }

        },
    },
    data: () => ({
        item_1: {
            name: 'test 1',
            checked: true,
            indeterminate: false
        },
        item_2: 
        {
            name: 'test 2',
            checked: false,
            indeterminate: true
        },
 })
})
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yeah, the default is missing sorry about that. Still, the issue exists. It's when the item_1 checked flag is true and the indeterminate flag is false. If I try to switch item_1 checked flag to false and interminate flag to true. when uncheking on item_2 checkbox.

Comment: I've updated the onTest method in above code , check with these changes now

Comment: https://codepen.io/kavin404/pen/rNNOXKB?editors=1010 here is the code. if I keep clicking on the second checkbox it will eventually start to just uncheck without going to indeterminate

Comment: Inside if condition you have kept both indeterminate and checked to true, the order of execution first it updates the indeterminate and then checked. The checked executes at the end and set it to true

Comment: Just set both indeterminate and checked to false if you uncheck the second box. Is that Right?

Comment: yeah switch between two status

Comment: If you need a switch you can go ahead with a radio button any one can be active, The logic with checkbox switching by using indertminate is same as using radio button

Comment: Still if you want to implement by checkbox use this codepen https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/eYYJOYN   Here, you can select only one at a time or both can be empty, you cannot select both at the same time, try this. I think this fits your requirement. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. I appreciate it :)

Comment: Accept the above answer as well, thanks for the appreciation